# what are the semantics for XSLT transformations of iregular documents such as HTML

Tags: html, xml, xaml, xslt

I'm doing a XAML to HTML transformation, and I've not ascertained quite well what is needed to match elements with arbitrary attributes and how to process sequential lists of elements that may have different structures below them, such that

```
<paragraph fontfamily="times">
 <run></run>
 <list></list>
</paragraph>
<paragraph fontsize="16">
 <run></run>
 <run></run>
 </paragraph>
```

would turn into

```
<p><span></span><ul></ul></p>
<p><span></span><span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT is a language based on top of [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) selectors.

In declarative style

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/paragraph"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="run"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph/list">
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph/run">
    <span>
        ...
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Also you could write it in imperative style

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/paragraph"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:for-each select="run">
            <span>
                ...
            </span>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="list">
            <ul>
                ...
            </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```